# Hot fix deployment on wildfly server

Tags: java, angular, linux, mongodb, wildfly

I want to deploy .class file on wildfly server
I have tried below points:

1. replace the .class file on below location:
   wildfly/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp6ca1b67d04c16296/content-abe7f47f1411854d/WEB-INF/classes/
   but changes not refleceted.
2. Also tried to restart wildfly service but chnages get override because after wildfly service restart .war file going to redeploy and changes get overridden.

Is it to possible to redeploy .class file on wildfly server without restart wildfly service

Answer (score 1):

You have several solutions but first thing first: once a class is loaded it doesn't matter what your changes are on the file system.
You need to replace the class in you application and redeploy it. This can be done in several ways depending on how it is deployed:

- use deployment overlay: http://docs.wildfly.org/29/wildscribe/deployment-overlay/index.html
- explode your deployment and replace the file (I'm not talking about files under deployments folder here): https://www.wildfly.org/news/2017/09/08/Exploded-deployments/
- use an exploded deployment and the deployment scanner